# TortoiseGit fails on clone and push

Tags: windows, git, version-control, ssh-keys, tortoisegit

TortoiseGit fals on cloning and push cloned repo.
I'm using ToroiseGit and msysgit. Using valid keys.

And console thing (git-cmd.bat) works correctly!
But TortoiseGit does't, what's wrong?

```
fatal: 'myrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (1734 ms @ 20.11.2013 2:26:18)
```

And in `/var/log/auth.log` I see:

```
Nov 20 05:36:06 myserver sshd[23529]: Accepted publickey for root from 22.228.217.4 port 52760 ssh2
Nov 20 05:36:06 myserver sshd[23529]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 20 05:36:06 myserver sshd[23529]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
```

Why root?

Comment: As I can see, TortoiseGit trying to login as root, but I'm requesting repo by typing git user (git@hostname.com:myrepo). Why?

Comment: I see it in `/var/log/auth.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it in mind, that if you use putty and TortoiseGit, and you have saved sessions in putty **with** username in url (root@myhost.com) - TortoiseGit will take this session and try to login as your user, except user that you set in repo-url. Read more @ https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html